# How to integrate PHPBB3.2.8 login onto my external website

Tags: html, css, phpbb3

REF: http://thefwf.xyz/2020/
REF: http://thefwf.xyz/b/

So as you can tell /b/ is where my PHPBB3 forums are located. The first link referenced is a direct link to my web site.

I would like to take the Login / Password box from PHPBB3 and essentially place it directly below the header video that I made. I simply do not know how to achieve this.

I've done lots of good searching.

Answer (score 0):

maybe similar this code help you but phpbb use form token that should post to the action url by username and password for login. 
if you can get form token from phpbb login is possible.

```
<form action="http://thefwf.xyz/b/ucp.php?mode=login" method="post">
<input type="text" name="username">
<input type="text" name="password">
<input type="hidden" name="form_token" value="[ form token ]">
<button type="submit">login</button>
</form>
```

Comment: I've added something very similar to this and got the css done so the style looks good. Unfortunatly some html/css doesn't actually do anything. There's no code that's triggering the login actually happening in connection with my phpBB forum. 

I understand you were essentially saying the same, in that, phpBB uses form token's and I should figure out how to connect the submit login button actually validating the form token and logging in the session.

More then likely some PHP at the top of my page is necessary. Just not sure which PHP to use... 

Thank you though.